# Can I enter Canada twice in a month as an American?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada

I will be visiting Canada twice during December. The first visit will be for 3 nights and second will be for 2 nights. The gap between the two visits will be one day where I will come back to the United States. The reason for both of the visits is for vacation. For personal information, I was born in the United States and have a valid passport. Will there be any issues with entering Canada twice in a month?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't be allowed into Canada - e.g. criminal history, previous immigration issues?

Comment: Nope. Have nothing on my criminal history or previous immigration issues. Mainly worried because of visiting Canada twice in such a short amount of time (one day between).

Comment: As long as you can explain your reasons if/when asked - you should be fine. I know the kids in Point Roberts WA go to Canada twice a day to get to and from high school.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I would guess those kids are fine as they have a valid reason of attending school in Canada. I was just worried Customs and Border might have something against people visiting twice within a short time frame for vacation.

Comment: (They actually attend school in the US, but due to a quirk of geography they live in an [exclave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_Roberts,_Washington) and must cross into Canada and back into the US to get to school, then back into Canada and into the US to go home.) So they enter Canada at least ten times a week.

Answer (score 8):

There's no reason that twice should be a problem. They'll probably ask why you're coming back so soon and you presumably have a good reason for travelling back and forth, so you've nothing to hide or worry about.

Comment: Exactly. I was born near Detroit, MI. Folks thought nothing of going over to Windsor to have lunch several times a week.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a problem.  I have done exactly this several times in the reverse direction, but it is equally fine northbound.  Once I did a day trip to the US from Canada on a Monday, then entered for a three-week holiday on the Thursday of the same week.  On another trip we spent several days in the US driving east toward Detroit, then crossed back into Canada, spent a week and a half in Toronto and Ottawa, and crossed back into the U.S. at Sault Ste. Marie, ON/MI and returned home to Saskatchewan that way.  Neither time was it an issue.

The only thing to watch: personal exemptions for imported items are based on the length of the current out-of-country travel.  For example, Canadians get an CAD$800 exemption after 48 hours, and I believe Americans get a US$800 exemption after 48 hours.  If you are out of the country for less than 48 hours, you would not be eligible for this exemption, even if your two foreign stays together exceed 48 hours.  (On the other hand, if both trips exceeded 48 hours, you'd get the exemption twice, once for each leg of the trip.)

Answer (score 2):

Unless your situation is special because of your history, US Citizens can visit Canada for up to 180 day, as often as they want. Nobody is going to trouble you if you go in and out every day, or several times in some weeks.